# Исключения java

Tags: java, исключения

помогите разобратся с кодом

```java
class MyDivByZero extends Exception {
    public void MyDivByZero() {
        System.out.println("Что такое? Вы решили делить на 0?");
    }
}
```

```java
class Arithmetic {
    public static double myDelete(double a, double b) throws MyDivByZero {
        double c;
        try {
            if (b == 0.0) {
                throw new MyDivByZero();
            }
            c = a / b;
        } catch (MyDivByZero e) {
            c = 0.0;
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("5.1, разделить на 1.2 будет "
                    + myDelete(5.1, 1.2));
            System.out.println("3.6, разделить на 0 будет "
                    + myDelete(3.6, 0));
            System.out.println("7.8, разделить на 3.9 будет "
                    + myDelete(7.8, 3.9));

        } catch (MyDivByZero e) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Код взят отсюда -> http://www.fandroid.info/isklyucheniya-v-java/

Я перенёс код в свою IDE и прошёлся по нему отладчиком.

Вопросы:

1.почему когда я вызвал конструктор `throw new MyDivByZero();` он ничего сделал? (хотя как я понимаю он должен был написать `System.out.println("Что такое? Вы решили делить на 0?");`)

2.зачем нужен try/catch в методе main()?

Comment: А вы добавьте внутри блока `} catch (MyDivByZero e) {`: `System.out.println(e);`, тогда получите ваше сообщение в консоли

Comment: Нужен, чтобы отловить деление на 0. Вы разве не видите? А вообще, я бы советовал использовать [ArithmeticException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) для этих целей, так-как, там уже учитывается, что происходит деление на ноль.. А и кстати, вроде как плавающие числа поддерживают деления на ноль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Все просто, это не конструктор, это метод под названием `MyDivByZero` мимикрирующий под конструктор и сбивающий Вас с толку, видите он возвращает `void` ?

   ```
   public void MyDivByZero() {
       System.out.println("Что такое? Вы решили делить на 0?");
   }
   ```
2. `try-catch` ловит брошенное исключение типа `MyDivByZero`, чтобы Вы могли узнать что произошло деление на 0.